# How can I require a dynamically generated module from a string?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using RequireJS to load files in the front end of a web application.

In some cases, I would like to have RequireJS load a string instead of a file. If this string was pasted into an actual `.js` file, and I required this file as a module through RequireJS, then I'd get a JavaScript object. For instance,

```
var str = "define([], function () { return {a : 'b'}; });";

var result = require(str) // I don't know what would be the syntax for this.
```

I'd like `result` to have the value `{a : 'b'}`

In my actual application the value of `str` is obtained from the server that serves my application and is variable.

So can I require a string like I've shown above?

Comment: It sounds like you want `eval()`.  Don't do that.

Comment: eval give the error : Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){ ............. however when i require from a file it works smoothly...

Comment: My front end application gets plain string code from server. That is the code i need to require at front end. The string code is not constant.. it may vary if server development team want to modify the code. Now how do i handle this situation..

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe try using the [Require.Js Text Plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text). It allows one to require "plain text" that can be loaded into a JavaScript variable.

Comment: the plugin mentioned above seems to require plain text file. There is no information or any example about the requiring string variable. Can you please link any live example for the same.

Comment: what do you mean requiring string variable? This plugin allows you to take the text from a file and have it as something that can be required. Did you look at the usage examples?

Comment: i dont have any file.. i just have a string as explained in question. and i want to require that string. in my question 'str' is a variable and i am seeking to require 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do *exactly* what you are proposing to do, because there's no syntax to get RequireJS to load a module from a string that contains the module's code.

However, there's a way to get the same result:

1. In your proposed system, the server generates the module's code and it sends right away to the client. Instead, the server could a) generate the module's code, and b) generate a unique module name that it associates with the code generated for the module and that it sends to the client.
2. The client requires the module name it has received from the server.
3. The server serves the module's code to the client (just like any other module the client requires).